# How to use the with clause and a union sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to use the with clause using a union for each location in the below query. I have tried multiple ways but have not been able to get this to work. I would then like to create a view out of the query.

```
WITH MaxLoadId AS
(
select MAX(t.loadid) AS loadid, p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
FROM tdataseg t
    INNER JOIN part p ON t.partitionkey = p.partitionkey
WHERE p.partname = 'MEXICO' 
GROUP BY p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
)
select distinct
mli.loadid AS loadid,
a.process_id,
mli.partitionkey,
-- t.partitionkey,
mli.partdesc,
mli.partname,
c.catname,
r.rule_name,
r.file_path,
a.execution_start_time,
a.execution_end_time,
a.records_processed,
a.status,
a.last_updated_by as processed_by,
a.last_update_date
FROM MaxLoadId mli
INNER JOIN datat ON mli.loadid = t.loadid
INNER JOIN details a ON mli.loadid = a.process_id
INNER JOIN category c ON t.catkey = c.catkey
INNER JOIN balances r ON t.RULE_ID = r.RULE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like the code sample below? You can specify multiple common table expressions first with a comma between each one then write a normal union query referencing each CTE.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS
WITH MaxLoadId AS
(
select MAX(t.loadid) AS loadid, p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
FROM tdataseg t
    INNER JOIN part p ON t.partitionkey = p.partitionkey
WHERE p.partname = 'MEXICO' 
GROUP BY p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
)
,MaxLoadId_Australia AS
(
select MAX(t.loadid) AS loadid, p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
FROM tdataseg t
    INNER JOIN part p ON t.partitionkey = p.partitionkey
WHERE p.partname = 'Australia' 
GROUP BY p.partitionkey, p.partdesc, p.partname
)
select distinct
mli.loadid AS loadid,
a.process_id,
mli.partitionkey,
-- t.partitionkey,
mli.partdesc,
mli.partname,
c.catname,
r.rule_name,
r.file_path,
a.execution_start_time,
a.execution_end_time,
a.records_processed,
a.status,
a.last_updated_by as processed_by,
a.last_update_date
FROM MaxLoadId mli
INNER JOIN datat ON mli.loadid = t.loadid
INNER JOIN details a ON mli.loadid = a.process_id
INNER JOIN category c ON t.catkey = c.catkey
INNER JOIN balances r ON t.RULE_ID = r.RULE_ID

UNION ALL 

select distinct
mli.loadid AS loadid,
a.process_id,
mli.partitionkey,
-- t.partitionkey,
mli.partdesc,
mli.partname,
c.catname,
r.rule_name,
r.file_path,
a.execution_start_time,
a.execution_end_time,
a.records_processed,
a.status,
a.last_updated_by as processed_by,
a.last_update_date
FROM MaxLoadId_Australia mli
INNER JOIN datat ON mli.loadid = t.loadid
INNER JOIN details a ON mli.loadid = a.process_id
INNER JOIN category c ON t.catkey = c.catkey
INNER JOIN balances r ON t.RULE_ID = r.RULE_ID
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks. How can i make this into a view?

Comment: I've edited my answer, simply add `CREATE VIEW schema.ViewName AS` at the start of the statement.